# Как сделать оффлайн карту на сайте используя Leaflet

Tags: javascript, карты

Я хочу сделать оффлайн карту для своего сайта, так как сайт будет использоваться локально и иногда даже без интернета. Мне нужна карта Казахстана, а так же я используя библиотеку Leaflet для отображения карты.

Comment: посмотрите пример работы с картой на ЮТубе, может быть поможет или натолкнет к решению вопроса: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NL60BIH63U